# Why string.Join(string delimiter, IEnumerable collection) returns string with only 1 value

Tags: c#, arrays, string, ienumerable

I am trying to create a method that will convert any IEnumerable to String (incl. Arrays).

When I try to pass array casted as an IEnumerable (not generic) to string.Join, it returns only 1 value as a result. The IEnumerable consists of various classes, which derive from a common ancestor and passes its 7 items correctly to the method:

```
var list = new List<SportEvent>
var array = new SportEvent[]
            {
                new SportMatch(),
                new SportMatch(),
                new SportMatchBase(),
                new SportMatch(),
                new SportEvent(),
                new SportEvent(),
                new SportEvent(),
            };

            bool isImplementingIEnumerable = list is IEnumerable;

if (isImplementingIEnumerable)
   {
      valueRepresentation = string.Join(", ", (IEnumerable)array);
   }
```

I am using this code just as a proof of concept. I will pass various collections to the method and I'm just testing with the code. Therefore, I do not want to bind to a single Type. I will just manually append values with StringBuilder.

Question is: Why string.Join(string pattern, IEnumerable collection) returns only 1 value?

Comment: `returns only 1 value` - what's the value? what are you expecting?

Comment: Could you expand on what you're trying to do, i.e. the expected result?

Comment: What is the point of testing `list is IEnumerable` if you never fill or use it?

Comment: You're passing in a `SportEvent[]` - `string.join` is expecting a `string[]`

Comment: So if the `list` is `IEnumerable` you call `string.Join` on the `array` - am I the only one to be confused by that?

Comment: @Filburt I will use IEnumerable, I will not pass SportPass[], but various types of IEnumerable objects.

Comment: @swiss196 edited problem description

Comment: @Alex In that case, I am receiving CheckClassToString.SportEvent[] and I'm expecting to receive .ToString overrides of all these classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I try to pass array casted as an IEnumerable (not generic) to
>   string.Join, it returns only 1 value as a result.

In the example you have provided you don't pass `IEnumerable` to `Join` method but an array of `SportEvent` objects. Notice that `Join` method has overloads for both [`object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Question is: Why string.Join(string pattern, IEnumerable collection)
>   returns only 1 value?

Because [`Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) is meant to return a single value which is a concatenation of string representation of each array element separated by a separator.

> I will pass various collections to the method and I'm just testing
>   with the code. Therefore, I do not want to bind to a single Type. I
>   will just manually append values with StringBuilder.

If I've interpreted your requirement correctly and your goal is to get a string representation of all objects independently from their type, so you can override `toString` method in the base class and, if necessary, in derived classes because `Join` method implicitly calls `toString` method of each element E.g.:

```
class SportMatchBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}

class SportEvent : SportMatchBase
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} ({Date.ToShortDateString()})";
    }
}

var array = new SportMatchBase[]
{
    new SportMatchBase() { Name = "Sport match" },
    new SportEvent() { Name = "Sport event", Date = DateTime.Now }
};

string valueRepresentation = string.Join<SportMatchBase>(", ", array);
```

Comment: Yes, I do override their .ToString method.